# How to configure mitmproxy to intercept https?

Tags: linux, proxy, https, http, mitmproxy

I am trying to use `mitmproxy` to debug some `https` requests. I have configured `mitmproxy` to listen to a certain port:

```
mitmproxy --listen-port 44700
```

I have configured my environment properly:

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:44700
export https_proxy=https://localhost:44700
```

And this is working for `http`:

```
» http http://www.example.org
```

is hitting `mitmproxy`, as expected.

Buuut `https` is failing:

```
» http https://www.example.org
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/http", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('httpie==0.9.2', 'console_scripts', 'http')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httpie/core.py", line 186, in main
    error('%s: %s', type(e).__name__, str(e))
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

Questions:

1. Do I need to configure another port in `mitmproxy` to listen to `https`?
2. How do I tell `http` (the tool) to trust the `mitmproxy` `CA`?

Answer (score 1):

The web gui is very comfortable. You can use `mitmproxy` instead.

1. Run the proxy server $ `mitmweb --listen-port 44700`
   Make sure that 44700 port is open in firewall. You can specify the IP of proxy with `--listen-host` flag. I.E. `--listen-host 192.168.0.10` or try `--listen-host 0.0.0.0` if can not access remotely.
2. Configure in the remote device the IP and port proxy.
3. Open browser in the remote device and go to http://mitm.it, is a local page, in a local DNS, that you can download and install the certs.
    If android, you must specify a pin lock screen.
4. Open web gui, by default in port 8081 in your browser: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/#/flows`
    Enjoy networks intercepts.

Answer (score 0):

confiure your device proxy to the ip/port, and open http://mitm.it on browser, and select a os to install CA.

more detail, you can refer to official documents

Comment: this doesn't look like a valuable answer